# Calculate a cumulative amount with a given time

Tags: window-functions, snowflake

I want to identify customers who have spent more than D dollars over a period of P hours. Suppose D=$10 and P=48. Then in the transaction data below:

```
CUSTOMER         STAMP        AMOUNT
--------         -----        ------
   A     2021-06-02 00:22:53    1.44
   A     2021-06-02 06:24:17    1.51
   A     2021-06-03 07:09:45    2.73
   A     2021-06-03 15:57:30    3.92
   A     2021-06-04 06:41:21    1.83
   B     2021-06-01 02:50:22    2.65
   B     2021-06-03 07:01:36    4.05
   B     2021-06-04 05:20:10    3.30
   B     2021-06-04 09:53:53    2.64
   B     2021-06-04 14:54:00    2.26
   C     2021-06-01 16:01:38    2.61
   C     2021-06-01 23:38:25    1.16
   C     2021-06-02 14:41:02    2.82
   C     2021-06-03 00:28:37    1.54
   C     2021-06-03 02:06:46    1.19
   C     2021-06-04 17:16:29    2.05
```

customer B meets the criteria and customers A and C do not (even though their total spend > $10).

I know how to use windowing functions, but in this case I don't know in advance how big the window should be.

---

I think [the answer](https://sonra.io/data-warehouse/window-function-rows-and-range-on-redshift-and-bigquery/) would be something like this:

```
select
  customer
, stamp
, amount
, amount > coalesce(sum(amount) over (order by extract('epoch_second', stamp)
range between 2*24*60*60 preceding and current row), 0) as is_alert
from t
where amount is not null
order by stamp
```

but my database is Snowflake and it [does not seem to support that syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-frame-syntax). That page says:

*For cumulative window frames:
...
RANGE is similar to ROWS, except it only computes the result for rows that have the same value as the current row (according to the specified ORDER BY subclause).*

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You say: `but in this case I don't know in advance how big the window should be.`. Well, in that case, it sounds to me like you require a UDF (user defined function) of some sort - sounds like you'll have to roll your sleeves up and get stuck into the manuals! You will then have to pass in your dollar amount D and your period time in hours P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake does support doing what you are asking, but with different syntax:

Here is the [script](https://gist.github.com/umjohndacosta/61f600fc61b5e5f369c6eaede06a8fe0):

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS demo;

create or replace table demo.customer_transactions(
  transaction_id integer identity
,customer varchar
,txn_date timestamp_ltz
,amount float
);

//
//CUSTOMER         STAMP        AMOUNT
//--------         -----        ------
insert into demo.customer_transactions (customer, txn_date, amount)
values
('A',     '2021-06-02 00:22:53',    1.44)
,('A',     '2021-06-02 06:24:17',    1.51)
,('A',     '2021-06-03 07:09:45',    2.73)
,('A',     '2021-06-03 15:57:30',    3.92)
,('A',     '2021-06-04 06:41:21',    1.83)
,('B',     '2021-06-01 02:50:22',    2.65)
,('B',     '2021-06-03 07:01:36',    4.05)
,('B',     '2021-06-04 05:20:10',   3.30)
,('B',     '2021-06-04 09:53:53',    2.64)
,('B',     '2021-06-04 14:54:00',    2.26)
,('C',    '2021-06-01 16:01:38',    2.61)
,('C',     '2021-06-01 23:38:25',    1.16)
,('C',     '2021-06-02 14:41:02',    2.82)
,('C',     '2021-06-03 00:28:37',    1.54)
,('C',     '2021-06-03 02:06:46',    1.19)
,('C',     '2021-06-04 17:16:29',    2.05)
;


select
*
,case when window_transaction_amount > 10.00 then 'warn' else 'ok' end as is_alert
from
(
select 
 a.transaction_id
,a.customer
,a.txn_date
,a.txn_date as window_start_date
,dateadd(hour,48, a.txn_date) as window_end_date
,a.amount
//,array_construct(b.transaction_id) as b_transactions
,listagg(distinct b.transaction_id,',') within group (order by b.transaction_id) as window_transaction_ids
,sum(b.amount) as window_transaction_amount
from demo.customer_transactions a left outer join demo.customer_transactions b on a.customer = b.customer and b.txn_date between a.txn_date and dateadd(hour,48, a.txn_date)
group by 
  a.transaction_id
,a.customer
,a.txn_date
,dateadd(hour,48, a.txn_date)
,a.amount
) q
order by 1,2,3;
```

The output you get is like this: [image]